# load user control dynamically with ajax AND have jquery document ready functionality

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

I have a user control that will load via

```
public static string RenderControl(Control control)
{
    var controlWriter = new StringWriter();
    var htmlWriter = new Html32TextWriter(tw);
    control.RenderControl(writer);
    htmlWriter.Close();            
    return controlWriter.ToString();
}
```

AJAX used to write the html

```
$('#testDiv').html(result.d);
```

This is called through an ajax Post. It loads the user control fine, but since the javascript document load has already fired I cannot use jquery's document.Ready.

My situation is **I need to load a user control dynamically and have jquery document.ready fire** , or some equivalent. I would rather not use an updatepanel but if that is the only means of getting this done then that is what I will use.

**What is an elegant solution to my problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in jQuery ajaxStop event to fire when an ajax call completes.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: Cool, i didn't know that event yet.

Comment: IF i have an html page render, then render more html inside of it with an ajax post would the html render inside of the main html have access to the ajaxStop?

Comment: @gh9: I'm not sure what you're asking. Once you have an ajaxStop callback registered, it will be triggered by any ajax request on the page - even an ajax request triggered by dynamically loaded content.

Comment: Good point, but that brings up another question, This will fire for every ajax stop. So if i have 3 controls with 3 ajax stops each ajax request will fire 3 different ajax stops correct?

Comment: The ajaxStop should be called from $(document) so it behaves similarly to .ready(). If you bind multiple callback functions to it then yes they'll each be called after every ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I solved something similar with a custom event that fires after the ajax contents were loaded and displayed.

Trigger the event inside the ajax function, after load and display:

```
$(document).trigger('ajaxLoadCallback');
```

And catch it in your document.ready script:

```
$(document).on('ajaxLoadCallback', function() {
    // Your ready functions
}
```

If you create a function for everything that should be executed after document.ready than you can call this function (e.g. `readyFunctions()`) on document.ready and after the firing custom event.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}

$(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
});
```

Comment: This is how I am calling the webMethod, but this has the problem of inserting the Document.Ready javascript after page load, thus the javascript does not run.

Comment: I dislike that because, that ties the usercontrol to the calling page. I cannot switch user controls on the fly without changing the calling page code.